Help with Mask brush Settings 4.2
I cannot figure out why my mask brush is jittery. To my knowledge, I've checked/unchecked all options that might be causing this problem, to no avail. How do I reset the brush to a smooth stroke, with no jitters or extraneous edges?
Update: This seems to be a universal brush setting issue, because this is happening with sculp>paint as well.
